# Use edition based redefinition from oracle with liquibase

Tags: oracle11g, liquibase

We would like to use the Edition Based Redifinition feature with Oracle.
Does anybody have experience creating updates with liquibase using this feature from Oracle?
I've checked in another forum  https://forum.liquibase.org/topic/how-to-do-an-alter-session and the test they did, it was not solved. 
Did somebody solve this and manage to use this feature from Oracle within liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

Finally we managed to solve it with liquibase.

We're executing a sqlFile changeset that executes ALTER SESSION SET EDITION =  and aftewards the changes we want to do.

It looks like the connection is properly changed and that we're able to do the changes in the proper version.